# what does the role of l.strip() in this statement

Tags: python

```
lines = [l.split() for l in inpf.readlines() if l.strip()]
```

In the above statement, what does `l.strip()` do?

```
lines = [l.split() for l in inpf.readlines()].
```

Will the above statement will not suffice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`strip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) removes any leading/trailing whitespace. so it will skip any lines that consist of nothing but whitespace or are empty.

On a side-note, there is no need to use `.readlines()` - you can iterate over the lines instead and thus avoid creating a second list which is thrown away right after the list comprehension finished:

```
lines = [l.split() for l in inpf if l.strip()]
```

Comment: As a side note, `str.split` will automatically strip any white space (`'\n'.split() == []`) so it is in fact redundant. `lines = [l.split() for l in inpf]` is enough or even `lines = map(str.split, inpf)` might be nicer.